# How to perform p2p behind 2 nats?

Tags: unix, tcp, udp, p2p, hole-punching

I'm trying to send 'hello' btw 2 clients, each behind a firewalled NAT, without success. UDP or TCP punching are just as fine, for now.

client A expecting to receive 'hello p':

```
set -- $( wget -qO- http://www.pschmidt.it/screenshooter/ss3.php | awk '{print $1, $2}'); echo $1 $2 $3 $4; `nc -l -v $2 ` & sudo hping3 -2 -c 30 -s $2 -p $4 $3
```

client B sending hello p:

```
set -- $( wget -qO- http://www.pschmidt.it/screenshooter/ss3.php | awk '{print $1, $2}'); echo $1 $2 $3 $4; sudo hping3 -2 -c 30 -s $2 -p $4 $3; echo "hello p" | nc -p $2 -u $3 $4
```

Unfortunately nothing is received.

Implementation inspired by http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/

Answer (score 1):

So, are both NATs *restricted cone NATs*? Do they deny port access when nothing went out on that / to the request source before?

You need to send a packet from one host to another, with the correct addresses and ports so the NATs then accept incoming requests even if they’re requests and not responses.

As an example:

PC1 - NAT1 - network - NAT2 - PC2

PC1 wants to access PC2 on port 10.

PC2 sends a request to PC1 with source port 10 (which is blocked by NAT1). PC1 sends a request to PC2 to port 10, which is then not blocked and will be responded.

Comment: > So, are both NATs restricted cone NATs?
I'm not sure how to classify the NATs, but as with Skype and P2P apps, I'd like it to consider the most restrictive. But in my case, it seems a restricted cone since the external IP doesn't change, but only the port.

Comment: so you mean the port needs to be the same both ways? I don't see any Rendezvous Server in your description.

Comment: They either have to know each others port, or need a rendezvous server which is accessible (not behind a NAT) and gives them each others port. In my example port 10 of PC2 was known. That needs to be known and PC2 needs to send a package in the correct moment. A rendezvous server would be the best, easiest solution. For synchronizing and managing.

Comment: With /restricted cone/ I was rather referring to whether they restrict incoming port access to only allow it from an IP and PORT that an outgoing msg was already sent to.

Comment: example code/demo that works, pls. The literature explains that behind symmetric NATs it's not possible even with STUN, and TURN needs to be used. Haven't found any code for TURN/ICE IM that demonstrates the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate which type of NATs you are dealing with. The 'symmetric' terminology is obsolete. You can read corresponding chapter from the Practical JXTA II book available online from scribd.

The technique you describe in your question will never work if neither of your peers have a public address. Solving this issue is more sophisticated and is not always possible.